# Label keeps on appearing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

SO I am using Python 3.4 and tkinter.

And when I call a function again n again which contains a label, the label keeps on appearing in window but previous label doesn't go away?

How can I remove any printed label from GUI window as soon as function is called and then display new one?

Here is the code:-

```
#def prestart():
    #here I check if number of match is okay, if not, user is redirected to setting else, I call start()

def start():

    #CPU Choice
    cpu_choice = Label(historyframe, text = "CPU Choosed: {}".format(dict['cpu_choice']))

    #Played Match
    #played_num_of_match = Label(scoreframe, text = "Number of Matches Played: {}".format(int(dict['match_played'])))

    #Display Status
    status_disp = Label(scoreframe, text = "Current Status: {}".format(dict['status']))

    if(int(dict['match_played']) < int(dict['num_of_match'])):
        playframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        historyframe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        status_disp.pack(fill=X)
    elif(int(dict['match_played']) == int(dict['num_of_match'])):
        playframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        historyframe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        status_disp.pack(fill=X)
        cp = dict['cpu_point']
        up = dict['user_point']
        result(cp, up)
    cpu_choice.pack(fill = X)
    scoreframe.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```

This function just updates the display!

```
def send_value(x):
    #Here I run logic of game and change value of key in dictionary and call start() at end of change.
```

Now, the choice buttons are not in any definition as they don't need to be called again n again. I just make playframe disappear n appear!
Here is the code for them:-

```
#Display Question
question = Label(playframe, text = "Rock? Paper? Scissor?")

#Rock
rock = Button(playframe, text = "Rock!", command = lambda: send_value("ROCK"))

#Paper
paper = Button(playframe, text = "Paper!", command = lambda: send_value("PAPER"))

#Scissor
scissor = Button(playframe, text = "Scissor!", command = lambda: send_value("SCISSOR"))
```

So when user clicks Rock/Paper/Scissor, I just change key value in dictionary! But if I keep the label outside function, it doesn't get auto updated!

Everything else is working perfectly. I'll kind of now start to make code cleaner.

Comment: Why not just update the text in the existing label? Also, show some code.

Comment: Are you simply trying to update the label? Why are you creating it within a function?

Comment: Please show us a MCVE that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead of creating a new label every time:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Window():

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.i = 0
        self.labelVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.labelVar.set("This is the first text: %d" %self.i) 

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = self.labelVar.get(), textvariable = self.labelVar)
        self.label.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Update", command = self.updateLabel)
        self.button.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

    def updateLabel(self):

        self.i += 1
        self.labelVar.set("This is new text: %d" %self.i)


root = tk.Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Important points:**

1) A class is used, as it is much easier to pass values around when all Tkinter objects and variables are member variables, accessible from all of your GUI functions.

2) `updateLabel` does not create a new Label. It simply updates the `StringVar()` object to hold new text every time you call the function. This is accomplished with the `textvariable = self.labelVar` keyword when creating my Label widget.

**PS**: This is done in **Python 2.5** so for this code to work for you, change `Tkinter` to `tkinter`

**EDIT 06/19/2015**:

If you want to implement something similar to what I have with your code, *without* using a class, you'll need to pass around references to your variables.

1) Change `start`:

Your Labels `cpu_choice`, `status_disp`, etc. should be created outside of the function; likely in the same location as `question`, `rock`, `paper`, `scissors`, etc. You will also pack them outside of the function as well. Same with all the calls to `.grid` inside of `start`; you shouldn't need to call `pack` or `grid` more than once: right when you create the widget.

The following lines:

```
    playframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    historyframe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    status_disp.pack(fill=X)
```

Can be done outside of the function as well; you execute these 3 statements under both the `if` and the `elif` conditions. This means they aren't really conditional statements; they are done regardless of the validity of the condition.

2) Create a `StringVar` for both `cpu_choice` & `status_disp` & edit the Labels as follows (remember, outside of the function):

```
    cpu_choice_text = StringVar()
    cpu_choice_text.set("Set this to whatever is shown at the start of the game")
    cpu_choice = Label(historyframe, text = cpu_choice_text.get(), textvariable = cpu_choice_text)
    cpu_choice.pack(fill = X)

    # And do this same thing for status_disp
```

3) When you call `start`, you will now pass it `cpu_choice_text` & `status_disp_text` (or whatever they are called). Instead of trying to change the `text` field of the Label frame, you may now use a `set` call on the `StringVar` which is connected to the Label & the Label will automatically update. Example:

```
    def start(cpu_choice_text, status_disp_text):
        cpu_choice.set(text = "CPU Choice: {}".format(dict['cpu_choice']))
        ...
```

Alternatively, wrap it all in a class and make it much easier for yourself by using `self` on every Tkinter variable & widget. In this way you won't need to pass variables to your functions, just access member variables directly as I have with `self.i`, `self.labelVar` in my example.

Comment: Even better, you can remove the use of a `StringVar` and directly update the label. That's one less object you have to manage.

Comment: I used .set and .get command. I had found it earlier but through your code only I understood how to use it. But I am not creating a class. What issues can I face?

Comment: It's not that you'll face *issues*, its just much harder to keep a reference to all the required variables without using a class. All GUI elements are member variables when you make a class (`self.someWidget`) and therefore are accessible within each function created inside the class, as seen in my example.

Comment: Hey thanks man. managed to do it. Yeah, now I have to do a little bit research on class because I dont have much idea about it! Thanks for help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `start` you create new labels and use `grid` to place them in the same spot as the old labels. The best solution is to only create the labels once, but if you insist on creating new labels each time `start` is called, you need to delete the old labels first.

You can use the `destroy()` method of a label to destroy it, though for that to work you must keep a global reference of the label.

Comment: I really like what maccartm did. But IDK how to implement it at this moment. I am working on it currently.. I think I do get what you mean. I'll give it a try hang on. Cuz I think I already did tried that..

Comment: It doesn't work. After destroying, I can't call it back again!